# Stack Overflow logo in new footer is red on Meta and blue on Main with Edge

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, footer, microsoft-edge

I'm using Microsoft Edge 40.15063.0.0 on Windows 10 for browsing, and when I look in the footer, I see something odd:

[image: Stack Overflow logo in footer on Meta]

The logo is all red on Meta. On Main, it's a lovely blue:

[image: Stack Overflow logo in footer on Main]

Granted, I might be the only person to browse SO using Edge, but it was a little surprising to see this.

I do not see these colors in Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: Really nothing we can do about that. Edge is blatantly ignoring the fill values in the SVG. That's completely a problem with the browser.

Comment: Don't feel bad; [there are 8 other people who also use Edge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-edge).

Comment: And here I was naively starting to think the tyranny of Microsoft's browsers breaking web standards, and forcing everyone to come up with IE-compliant hacks and contingencies, came to an end...

Comment: No way, @Dragomok. IE-compliant hacks are fast becoming a thing of the past. We call them "Edge-cases" now.

Comment: Thanks @animuson I didn't realize that was an issue with Edge. Good to know. If it's not already an issue on their bug tracker thing I'll add it.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Looking into it more, it seems to be a problem with their attribute selector or fill property. E.g. these are all being ignored by Edge, but applied by other browsers: `.s-footer._short .-logo path[fill="#222426"]{fill:#0C0D0E}.s-footer._short .-logo path[fill="#bcbbbb"],.s-footer._short .-logo path[fill="#BCBBBB"]{fill:#BCBBBB}.s-footer._short .-logo path[fill="#f48024"],.s-footer._short .-logo path[fill="#F48024"]{fill:#F48024}`

Comment: @animuson Looks like Edge is being case-sensitive with the attribute name: `document.querySelectorAll('.s-footer._short .-logo path[fill="#222426"]')` returns an empty NodeList, but `document.querySelectorAll('.s-footer._short .-logo path[FILL="#222426"]')` returns a NodeList with the correct element...

Comment: Heh leave it to Edge. I suppose an easy fix that doesn't break anything for anyone else is to just lower-case those attributes in our SVG. (Though this really should be reported to Edge because that's not how it should work.)

Comment: Interesting - I've seen this bug long time ago when I was working on footer and I was pretty sure I fixed it (it actually still works on my MS Edge 38.14393.1066.0 - which seems to be older than yours). i fixed the issue because my version of Edge was case sensitive but only for value.. According to your investigation it seems like newer Edge is also case-sensitive for attributes name.. Anyway, I will take a closer look at this. I just need to find someone (around) using Edge....

Comment: Well, I added "Feedback" via Microsoft's Feedback Hub: https://aka.ms/Mk13o7, as that seems to be their preferred method. We'll see what happens.

Comment: I lost a bet. I bet no one was using edge. Thanks bro.

Comment: That was not a good bet, @Philly. There are still people using IE 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paweł adjusted the selector/SVG to match casing, so Edge can find the right elements and style them.